# When does apc.ini get generated when compiling APC

Tags: php, ubuntu, apc

I am writing a shell script to update APC on my Ubuntu 10.04 x86_64 build. When I compile APC originally (fresh system, first time install) it generates the following file:

```
/etc/php5/conf.d/apc.ini
```

All my update script does is download the new set of source files, compile them, and install over the old version. When I compile the new version of APC I pass ./configure the same arguments I did during the original install. I was expecting it to generate a new apc.ini file and stomp my old one. However it does not seem to be doing that.

Why is it not overwriting my old apc.ini? When in the compilation/install process is apc.ini generated? Is this normal behavior that I can rely on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it generates the config file when you run `./configure`, attempts to move it to the actual destination when you run `make install`, but it will not overwrite an existing copy of the file simply because you may have customized it and wouldn't want it to be changed (or lost) when upgrading.

You should be able to find a copy of the generated conf file in one of the build directories though.  Search for apc.ini or similar names after you have run configure.